# Can't Edit Global Variable Inside Function

Tags: javascript

I'm declaring the global variable `str`, then editing it inside a function, and trying to call it within that function. However, when called, it returns the initial global value of `''`.

```js
var str = '';
function getProjects(service) {
  //find all projects

    fetch(`http://localhost:8888/wp-json/wp/v2/projects?_embed`)
      // get the response as JSON
      .then(r => r.json())
      // go through the posts and append each posts' title to the HTML element
      .then(projects => {
        //for each project, find categories
        projects.forEach(project => {
          // find categories of each project
          project.categories.forEach(category => {
            // check if category name is equal to a service name
            fetch(`http://localhost:8888/wp-json/wp/v2/categories/${category}`)
              .then(r => r.json())
              .then(response => {
                if(serviceData[service].slug == response.slug) {
                  // if previous evaluates to true, add project to service
                  if(project._embedded['wp:featuredmedia']) {
                    str += `<div class='project-div'><a href='#'><img src='${project._embedded['wp:featuredmedia'][0].media_details.sizes.medium.source_url}' /><div class='bottom-text'>${project.title.rendered}</div></a></div>`;
                  }
                }
              })
          })
        })

      })
      .then(() => {
        document.getElementById('projects-container').innerHTML = str;
      })
}
```

Comment: `str` is set "long" after you're accessing it. `fetch()` fires off a network request, which will finishes at some arbitrary point in the future. Everything you want to with the received data has to go into the callback function. Also, debugging 101: add `console.log()` calls to find out where and how your functions fail. It looks like maybe `str` is never changed because your code doesn't work like you expect it to?

Comment: You are using a _grave accent `\``_ as text delimiter when assign the `str` value. Does the issue occur if you use e.g. double quote `"`?

Comment: @ChrisG Thanks. I moved `document.getElementById('projects-container').innerHTML = str;` into a `.then()` of the second fetch and it seems to be working now!

Comment: @David In the long run you'll want to `map()` the array elements to an array of `fetch()`s and use `Promise.all()`.

Answer (score 0):

In the 2rd then() handler return the `str` and accept it as a parameter in the 3rd then() handler like this below

```
              if(project._embedded['wp:featuredmedia']) {
                //...
                return str;
              }
            }
          })
      })
    })

  })
  .then((str) => {
    document.getElementById('projects-container').innerHTML = str;
  })
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use a regular for loop rather than a forEach. Higher order functions native to array prototypes are not compatible with promisified functions. Try changing it to a for loop and see if that fixes your problem.

Also, to demonstrate how a forEach breaks your code, console log right after you append to the string and then console log right before you use that edited string. More than likely you will see the latter console log happening before the ones in the forEach.

Comment: Both `projects` and `project.categories` are most likely basic arrays, given that they're part of the response, not promises.

Comment: I understand that projects and project.categories are basic arrays and not promises, however he is trying to call a promise based function inside of his forEaches (fetch). While that call will be successful, the forEach will not wait until he enters the "then" before moving on. Therefore, his forEach will terminate before he enters the "then" once and will enter the last "then" before that, where he accesses an unedited str.

Comment: I switched both forEach loops over to for loops and it still did not work

Comment: @David the problem is, as Alex is pointing out, that those `fetch()` calls in your inner loop all return their own promises, but nothing waits for all of them to finish.